# Cipher in C program doesn't change text file

Tags: c, encryption

In this program, I've used the simple substitution cipher on a text file named "message" in the same folder as the program. However when I run it, the message doesn't change from "abcdefg". I've looked at the code numerous times but I don't see the problem, maybe I'm just a amateur in C. Anything to help is much appreciated. Thanks!

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>   

const int MAXSIZE = 50;
void Encrypt(FILE *File, char file[MAXSIZE], int i)  
{
    File = fopen("message.txt", "r+");    

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {

        if (file[i] == 'a')
        {
            file[i] = 'F';
            fputc(file[i], File);
        }

        if (file[i] == 'b')

        {
            file[i] = 'G';
            fputc(file[i], File);
        }

        if (file[i] == 'c')
        {
            file[i] = 'Z';
            fputc(file[i], File);
        }

        if (file[i] == 'd')
        {
            file[i] = 'V';
            fputc(file[i], File);
        }


        if (file[i] == 'e')
        {
            file[i] = 'A';
            fputc(file[i], File);
        }


        if (file[i] == 'f')
        {
            file[i] = 'B';
            fputc(file[i], File);
        }


        if (file[i] == 'g')
        {
            file[i] = 'G';
            fputc(file[i], File);
        }


        if (file[i] == 'h')
        {
            file[i] = 'X';
            fputc(file[i], File);
        }

        if (file[i] == 'i')
        {
            file[i] = 'E';
            fputc(file[i], File);
        }

        if (file[i] == 'j')
        {
            file[i] = 'J';
            fputc(file[i], File);
        }

        if (file[i] == 'k')
        {
            file[i] = 'I';
            fputc(file[i], File);
        }

        if (file[i] == 'l')
        {
            file[i] = 'K';
            fputc(file[i], File);
        }

        if (file[i] == 'm')
        {
            file[i] = 'O';
            fputc(file[i], File);
        }


        if (file[i] == 'n')
        {
            file[i] = 'V';
            fputc(file[i], File);
        }

        if (file[i] == 'o')
        {
            file[i] = 'U';
            fputc(file[i], File);
        }

        if (file[i] == 'q')
        {
            file[i] = 'Y';
            fputc(file[i], File);
        }

        if (file[i] == 'r')
        {
            file[i] = 'N';
            fputc(file[i], File);
        }


        if (file[i] == 's')
        {
            file[i] = 'P';
            fputc(file[i], File);
        }


        if (file[i] == 't')
        {
            file[i] = 'R';
            fputc(file[i], File);
        }


        if (file[i] == 'u')
        {
            file[i] = 'C';
            fputc(file[i], File);
        }


        if (file[i] == 'v')
        {
            file[i] = 'Q';
            fputc(file[i], File);
        }


        if (file[i] == 'w')
        {
            file[i] = 'T';
            fputc(file[i], File);
        }


        if (file[i] == 'x')
        {
            file[i] = 'D';
            fputc(file[i], File);
        }


        if (file[i] == 'y')
        {
            file[i] = 'S';
            fputc(file[i], File);
        }


        if (file[i] == 'z')
        {
            file[i] = 'H';
            fputc(file[i], File);
        }
    }

    printf("Check the file for encrypted message!\n\n");

    fclose(File);
    return;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    char file[MAXSIZE];
    FILE *File = 0;

    Encrypt(File, file, i);   

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your input buffer is empty (not initialized). From where do you want to get the clear text?

Answer (score 0):

Your input buffer is never initialized. Add this after file open:

```
fgets(file, MAXSIZE, File);
/* todo: check for error */
```

If you want to overwrite the message, use `rewind(File)`.
And write a newline when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

In function `Encrypt()`, after opening the file you haven't actually read data from the file into the string `file`.

You could use `fgets()` to read from the open file into the string `file` like

```
fgets(file, sizeof(file), File);
```

It should be noted that `fgets()` will read in the trailing `\n` to the string.

After reading the line the file pointer would've advanced and you need to get it back to its original position before writing.

You could save the current position in a variable, read from file and set the file pointer back using the saved value with `fseek()`.

```
long currentPos=ftell(File);
fgets(file, MAXSIZE, File);
fseek(File, currentPos, 0);
```

Also, instead of the multiple `if`s, it would be better to `else if`s after the first `if`.
In this way, the `if`s after the matched `if` needn't be examined.

Or you could do away with all those annoying `if`s and do something like

```
char original[]="abcdefghijklmnoqrstuvwxyz";
char translation[]="FGZVABGXEJIKOVUYNPRCQTDSH";
for(j=0; translation[j]!='\0'; ++j)
{
    if(file[i]==original[j])
    {
        file[i]=translation[j];
        fputc(file[i], File);
    }
}
```

And the use of `system("pause")` is not considered a good practice. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong).